# Android - Google Maps, Google Play Services library referencing

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, google-play-services

Is there any better way (easy) to reference the Google Play Services lib(.jar)
than, importing the Google Play Services project from Android SDK directory into Current project's Eclipse workspace?

P.s.:- Because this is bit confusing for a novice android developer!!!
Thanks for your advice in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the .jar file inside the libs folder of imported library(...\android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs).

But referencing only that jar file may be improper. I tried to do so for google maps, but didn't work. Suggested way is to ***import that library project to the workspace*** and refer the whole.

Comment: Yap, that's right reffering that imported project as a library isn't it?
There was a little work around and that twisted my head!
Thanks!
Any suggestions?